# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended with INSERT INTO...SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I fix my problem by chance, but I really want to know why it works :),

Here's the thing:

I get the `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` Error when I execute the following SQL statement:

```
  INSERT INTO BASP_DX.QLR@GT(BDCDYH, QSZT)
  SELECT NVL(e.BDCDYH, ' '),b.LIFECYCLE AS QSZT
  FROM DJ_DY a
    LEFT JOIN DJ_XGDJGL d
      ON d.ZSLBH = a.SLBH
    LEFT JOIN DJ_DJB e
      ON e.SLBH = d.FSLBH
        AND e.SLBH = '0123456789'
    LEFT JOIN DJ_QLRGL f
      ON f.SLBH = e.SLBH
        AND f.QLRLX = 'Person1'
    LEFT JOIN DJ_QLRGL b
      ON b.SLBH = a.SLBH
        AND (b.QLRLX = 'Person2' OR (b.QLRLX = 'Person3' AND b.QLRID = f.QLRID))
  WHERE a.SLBH = '12345'
    AND e.SLBH IS NOT NULL
    -- add the condition to ensure that 
    -- this statement and the second statement get the same result 
    AND b.QLRID IS NOT NULL
    AND (a.LIFECYCLE = '0' OR a.LIFECYCLE IS NULL);
```

I remove all the unnecessary insert value, related table and condition from the original SQL statement, to focus on the problem part.

Then I google it, from this [post](http://www.databasestar.com/ora-00933/) I know the causes may be:

1. An INSERT statement with an ORDER BY clause or an INNER JOIN
2. A DELETE statement with an INNER JOIN or ORDER BY clause
3. An UPDATE statement with an INNER JOIN

Apparently, these are not my type. I didn't use the INNER JOIN and ORDER BY, all I use is LEFT JOIN statement, so I wonder it might be reason that I set too many conditions with the LEFT JOIN statement (such as `LEFT JOIN DJ_QLRGL b`), so I try move the conditions after WHERE clause, it looks like this:

```
  INSERT INTO BASP_DX.QLR@GT(BDCDYH, QSZT)
  SELECT NVL(e.BDCDYH, ' '),b.LIFECYCLE AS QSZT
  FROM DJ_DY a
    LEFT JOIN DJ_XGDJGL d
      ON d.ZSLBH = a.SLBH
    LEFT JOIN DJ_DJB e
      ON e.SLBH = d.FSLBH
        AND e.SLBH = '0123456789'
    LEFT JOIN DJ_QLRGL f
      ON f.SLBH = e.SLBH
        AND f.QLRLX = 'Person1'
    LEFT JOIN DJ_QLRGL b
      ON b.SLBH = a.SLBH
    -- this conditions move to WHERE clause
  WHERE a.SLBH = '12345'
    AND e.SLBH IS NOT NULL
    -- here is the original LEFT JOIN condition
    AND (b.QLRLX = 'Person2' OR (b.QLRLX = 'Person3' AND b.QLRID = f.QLRID))
    AND (a.LIFECYCLE = '0' OR a.LIFECYCLE IS NULL);
```

Then it works!
But why?

I just want to know the reason for this situation.

---

`Solution`

the problem is triangular join, the LEFT JOIN conditions can't contain the condition concerning both the self join table, in this case, it's `b.QLRID = f.QLRID`, so when I remove the `b.QLRID = f.QLRID` condition, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the join of "DJ_QLRGL b" is not LEFT any more,
 as WHERE condition excludes rows with no b counterpart found

Comment: thanks for reply, I don't get it, Do you mean that I join the `DJ_QLRGL` twice is the reason I get the `ORA-00933` error???

Comment: The two SQLs you provided are not equivalent.

Rows with no "b.SLBH = a.SLBH" found will be absent in query 2

Comment: Yes, you are right! I should add the `AND b.QLRID is not null` after the where clause in the first SQL statement~~~but I still want to know the reason why the second SQL statement works, any clues??

Comment: Triangular join may be the cause. Did you try expressing the same in Oracle join syntax, e.g. listing all the tables in `FROM` clause and all join conditions in `WHERE` ?

Comment: I follow you advice, use the Oracle join syntax, it works fine, then I google `triangular join` since I didn't know what it is :) , I get there are two factor of triangular join: 1. table join back to itself; 2. the join is based on an inequality from [here](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/working-with-triangular-joins.html). In the second statement, `DJ_QLRGL` still join back to itself, but it works, so the problem is not the first one. May be somthing wrong with the condition? May be somthing wrong with the condition concerning two `DJ_QLRGL`? remove the condition `b.QLRID=f.QLRID`, it works^_^

Comment: So, I think the problem is that the conditon concerning both self join table, we can't use such a condition after the LEFT JOIN, BTW, maybe the Oracle join syntax is the best way to do such a thing~~~Thank a lot